# Is the passage of an unconstitutional law "lawless action" for the purpose of First Amendment protection?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-constitution, freedom-of-speech, us-federal-government

Speech intended to incite imminent lawless action is not protected by the First Amendment. Is the passage of an unconstitutional law "lawless action" for this purpose? Suppose someone who is not a congressperson (to prevent the Speech and Debate Clause from being relevant) somehow communicates with members of a house of Congress while they are in session, promoting the passage of an unconstitutional law. (Assume the law is blatantly unconstitutional, so there is no question of whether or not it is constitutional; for example, it may forbid all religious gatherings.) Does this speech fall within the "imminent lawless action" exception to First Amendment protection?

Answer (score 4):

It is not illegal for Congress to pass a law, even if the law itself is eventually overturned as unconstitutional. Nor, BTW, is it illegal for a court to enter a ruling that ends up being overturned by some higher or later court.

Since the act in question are not unlawful, advocating that the actions be taken is not incitement of unlawful action. We need not even look at the question of immediateness (this "immediate lawless action" thing means "go out right now and burn down").

Comment: Or Reverend Stryker pulling a pistol, aiming at Ms. Pryde and yelling "Let's kill a mutant".

Comment: Do you have any authority supporting these conclusions? This seems like pure guesswork, and also probably incorrect.

Comment: @bdb484 The answer definitely reaches the correct conclusion. The lack of immediacy is, IMHO, the easier way to be certain of that. But the reasoning of the initial argument also seems solid. Admittedly, authority is always better.

Comment: I agree that it's not "imminent," but I don't understand the argument that it's not "lawless." If the First Amendment says "Congress shall make no law" abridging the free exercise of religion or freedom of assembly, and then Congress makes a law abridging the free exercise of religion and the freedom of assembly, how is that anything other than lawless?